# Is it possible to implement ssl false start on Android

Tags: android, https, ssl

Per google chrome team log, they implemented SSl false start in chrome 9, and got a huge decrease in ssl connection setup time. 
   I am developing an android application which need talk to server through https connections, but there is huge latency problem when using https connection. I am much curious if it is possible to make the false start change as google do in chrome browser? I've looked into android http apis and apache httpclient apis, no lucky so far.

Comment: They seem to have given up on it: http://www.imperialviolet.org/2012/04/11/falsestart.html

Comment: @Bruno The link is helpful. seems I need to figure out another way for better performance